# Android: Create java .jar library for common classes in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I followed every tutorial I found, here's what I tried so far

1. Properties > java build Path > Projects > add the project
2. Properties > Source > link source > folders of java classes in other project
3. Create jar of common classes project > java build path > Libraries > add the jar
4. Also tried copying the jar into the project's lib and the adding in build path.

My project will compile, recognizing the classes (Example I have com.mydom.util.NetworkUtil.java)

I build and run the android app and when it reaches the call for a static method, I get this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mydom.util.NetworkUtil
```

I know I can just copy the classes over to my main project, but I'd like to keep it in a separate project because it is shared by another project.

What am I doing wrong in trying to add this source. Thanks.

Comment: i guess com.mydom.util.NetworkUtil.java is missing in your workspace ...

Comment: It's in my workspace. Also eclipse sees it, and building the project work. I get the FATAL EXCEPTION at runtime. I also did a create .jar and then copied this jar into the lib directory and added in the build path. Same problem.

Comment: @ibaralf Did you try [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-how-to-solve-no-class-def-found-error/)